# how to add css and js in the footer in magento 2?

Tags: javascript, css, magento-2.1.8

Currently, CSS and JS added in head section `default_head_blocks.xml`.

But I want to add in the footer. In which I need to put the css and js?

Answer (score 0):

As the `css` and `script` layout xml tag will only work inside `head` I think you'll need to create a block as a child of `before.body.end` and load your CSS/JS files manually there.

Alternatively you could do that directly in layout XML like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="exampleScript">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/example-script.js"></script>]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Although that wouldn't work well for local assets as you'd have to hard code the pub/media URL which wouldn't work if you have versioning enabled.